# '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'rezisable'

Tags: python, tkinter

Выдает ошибку но сделал все как писали, даже после того как просто скопировал с сайта готовый код все равно ошибка,помогите пожалйста что не так python 3.8.5

```
from tkinter
import *
import time
import random
tk = Tk()
tk.title('Game')
tk.rezisable(0, 0)
tk.wm_attributes('-topmost, 1')
canvas = Canvas(tk, width = 500, heidht = 400, highlightthickness = 0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()

class Ball:
  def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, score, color):
  self.canvas = canvas
self.paddle = paddle
self.score = score
self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill = color)
self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
starts = [-2, -1, 1, 2]
random.shuffle(starts)
self.x = starts[0]
self.y = -2
self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_widht()
self.hit_bottom = False
def hit_paddle(self, pos):
  paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
  if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
  self.score.hit()
return True
return False
def draw(self):
  self, canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
if pos[1] <= 0:
  self.y = 2
if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
  self.hit_bottom = True
canvas.create_text(250, 120, text = 'Вы выиграли', font = ('Corier', 30), fill = 'red')
if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
  self.y = -2
if pos[0] < -0:
  self.x = 2
if pos[2] >= self.canvas_widht:
  self.x = -2
class Paddle:
  def __init__(self, canvas, color):
  self.canvas = canvas
self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill = color)
start_1 = [40, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 200]
random.shuffle(start_1)
self.starting_point_x = start_1[0]
self.canvas.move(self.id, self.starting_point_x, 300)
self.x = 0
self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Rigth>', self.turn_rigth)
self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
self.started = False
self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Rerutn>', self.start_game)
def turn_rigth(self, event):
  self.x = 2
def turn_left(self, event):
  self.x = 2
def start_game(self, event):
  self.started = True
def draw(self):
  self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
if pos[0] <= 0:
  self.x = 0
elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
  self.x = 0
class Score:
  def __init__(self, canvas, color):
  self.score = 0
self.canvas = canvas
self.id = canvas.create_text(450, 10, text = self.score, font = ('Courier', 15), fill = color)
def hit(self):
  self.score += 1
self.canvas.itemconfig(self.id, text = self.score)
score = Score(canvas, 'green')
paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'White')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, score, 'red')
while not ball.hir_nottom:
  if paddle.started == True:
  ball.draw()
paddle.draw()
tk.update()
tim.sleep(0.01)
time.sleep(3)
```

вот сама ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/ПУТЬ puthon/ball.py", line 6, in <module>
    tk.rezisable(0, 0)
  File "C:\Users\Я\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2345, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'rezisable'
>>>
```

Comment: для начала отформатируйте текст  и проверьте чтобы он запускался.

Comment: в python отступы имеют значение при исполнении

Comment: *"Не пойму в чём"*... Если прочитать текст ошибки, а не сразу копировать его на SO, можно узнать много интересного. Например, что в строке №6 у Вас вызывается `tk.rezisable(0, 0)`, при этом `tk` – объект класса `_tkinter.tkapp`, у которого нет метода `rezisable`. Чисто интуитивно могу предположить, что метод должен называться `resizable`, а не `rezisable`, т.к. является английским словом и первый вариант – явно опечатка.